# shell loop & find get filename only, called from PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell, find

I am trying to get all the files from find into the output format using part of the original filename without extension plus Frame55Grab%d.bmp

```
$e= shell_exec('find  . -regex ./video/".*\.\(mp4\)" "$i"  -exec bash -c \'./ffmpeg -i {}  -vf fps=1/8 /home3/tcokchal/public_html/ffmpeg3/${i%%.*}Frame55Grab%d.bmp\'  - {} \; 2>&1 ' );
```

This doesn't work, giving me

find: paths must precede expression: 
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

Comment: `shell_exec()` is code in what language? (I ask because *hopefully* you're using something that gives you a means of interacting with a shell with fewer security bugs than `system()`, which it appears to be a wrapper around).

Comment: @charles It can be php^

Comment: If it were *tagged* PHP, it would have hit my ignore filter, and I wouldn't be seeing it. Time to correct that. :)

Comment: A shame, it's beautiful! ;)

Comment: Thinking this could be done with [Glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and some variable processing...

Comment: Its in PHP. I couldn't find out how it was done so I started to build a scandir with glob because Im more familiar with PHP, but I came across countless FFMPEG errors.